# Fail minimizing to system tray in C#

Tags: c#, minimize

I want to minimize my program to the system tray by clicking an entry in the system menu of the form.
So first I created a notify icon and a context menu:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  this.components = new Container();
  ...
  this.notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
  this.contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
  this.contextMenuItem1 = new MenuItem();
  this.contextMenuItem2 = new MenuItem();
  this.SuspendLayout();

  this.notifyIcon.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu;
  this.notifyIcon.Text = "Test";

  this.contextMenu.Name = "contextMenu";
  this.contextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[]
  {
    this.contextMenuItem1,
    this.contextMenuItem2
  });

  this.contextMenuItem1.Name = "contextMenuItem1";
  this.contextMenuItem1.Text = "&Show";
  this.contextMenuItem1.Click += new EventHandler(this.contextMenuItem1_Click);

  this.contextMenuItem2.Name = "contextMenuItem2";
  this.contextMenuItem2.Text = "&Exit";
  this.contextMenuItem2.Click += new EventHandler(this.contextMenuItem2_Click);
}
```

Then I extended the system menu:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int hmenu = GetSystemMenu(Handle, 0);
  AppendMenu(hmenu, 0xA00, 0, null);
  AppendMenu(hmenu, 0, 111, "M&inimize to system tray");
}
```

A click on this menu item should fade out the main window:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  base.WndProc(ref m);
  if (m.Msg == 0x112)
  {
    if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 111)
    {
      Visible = false;
      Hide();
      notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }
  }
}
```

A click in the context menu have to reshow the program window or close the whole application:

```
private void contextMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  notifyIcon.Visible = false;
  Show();
  Visible = true;
}

private void contextMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Close();
}
```

My problem is now the following:
If I click the new entry to minimize then the WndProc method is executed successfully and the form will be hidden but no item with the caption "Test" is displayed in the system tray.
And then there's also another window visible. I think that comes from .NET but the window is completely empty so I'm not sure. Normally I should fallback to the exe file in windows explorer which starts my program, isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

+++ EDIT +++

I found out that the empty window behind my application was the console window. I only forgot to compile my project with the winexe parameter.

Comment: Get your NotifyIcon working first.  One obvious flaw in the snippet is that you forgot to set its Icon property.  Required.  Next thing to check is to make sure it didn't end up in the overflow area.

Comment: I didn't know that it's strongly necessary to set the icon property. Now my notify icon works. But there's still the problem of the .NET window after hiding the main form.